# Why does my array contain letters that I have not entered?

Tags: c++, arrays, histogram

I'm having trouble with a piece of code. I'm trying to calculate a histogram inside a boolean function. I have this piece of code that I've written for another program, that I know works. The difference now is that it's inside a if and else if statement. The program takes a string from the user and stores that in an array. The array is looped through and is expected to calculate the number of letters, example the total number of H:s entered and also the total number of letters entered, example a total of 10 letters entered.

What I'm getting right now is, let's say I enter the text: "hello". I get a total number of 7 (always two more than I entered, but not if I enter a empty string). And it's always an extra "H" and "O". So for "hello", I get:
e: 1
h: 2
l: 2
o: 2

I have absolutely no clue what's going on here, and I'm not really sure what to search for either. I'm quite new with C++.

```
bool Text::beraknaHistogramAbs(){
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

if (inText.empty()){
    cout << "Tom textrad!" << endl;
    exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

}

else if(!inText.empty()) {
    for (i = 0; i < ANTAL_BOKSTAVER; i++){ //ANTAL_BOKSTAVER is 26.
        if (inText[i] >= 'a' && inText[i] <= 'z'){ //inText is the string from the user.
            j = inText[i] - 'a';
            ++absolutHisto[j]; //Is initialized to zero in the default constructor.
    }
        if (inText[i] >= 'A' && inText[i] <= 'Z'){
            j = inText[i] - 'A';
            ++absolutHisto[j];
    }
}
for (i = 0; i < ANTAL_BOKSTAVER; i++){
    antal += absolutHisto[i]; //antal is an integer for the total number of letters.
}
return true;
}
}
```

I guess I'm having problem with the else if statement, since this piece of code is working in another program, where it's passed through an while loop.

EDIT!! To show how inText is created.

```
void Text::setText(const string &nyText){

cout <<"Ge en rad med text:" << endl;
getline(cin,inText);
```

Comment: please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please try to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's impossible to diagnose the issue right now because, for example, we can't see the declaration of `inText`, nor the process by which it is populated.

Comment: You let `i` loop from 0 to 26 and you use that to access `inText`. Shouldn't you let `i` stop at `inText.length()` instead?

Comment: Time to try out your debugger ... and single step.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel How can I pass a minimum amount of code when it's clear that the problem is in this function?

Comment: @Botje hmm, as written above it's working fine in another program. I don't think that's the problem, but please prove me wrong.

Comment: I can't "prove you wrong" without you showing how `inText` is created and filled, as someone else said.

Comment: @Botje I'll take care of that! (EDIT: Done)

Comment: Are you using c-strings?  In that case you will see the string termination character '\0'
If so, use `std::string` instead

Comment: Assume `inText="hello"`. What does `inText[20]` access?

Comment: @Botje it's empty. Nothing there.

Comment: That's what you think. In reality, the processor will dutifully index *past* the end of your string and read whatever memory is there. You will hear this referred to as "undefined behavior", too. It is your responsibility to make sure you never go past `inText[inText.length() - 1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An edit has shown that the loops are reading past the end of the input string.

The first loop after the `!inText.empty()` check should be

```
for (i = 0; i < inText.length(); i++)
```

Alternatively, you could just write the whole thing as:

```
for (const char x : inText) {
    if (x >= 'A' && x <= 'Z') { absolutHisto[x-'A']++; }
    if (x >= 'a' && x <= 'z') { absolutHisto[x-'a']++; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! The output is now what I expect. "hello" gives me 5 characters and the histogram prints as expected. I really appreciate the help, thank you.

Comment: The two conditions inside the loop could be made more readable by using islower(x) and isupper(x). It would be more efficient to put the second if in an else clause of the first if, as a character can't be both lower and upper.